# How overlap 2 images with keypoints in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, merge, keypoint

I try to create a new picture (map) from 2 blueprints but the code is not correct.

There is an overlap between the 2 picture and I tried to find it and merge them. I'm a beginner using opencv and python so I tried to find it like that, but it's not working properly every time. If I miss converting the pictures to grayscale and blur it, sometimes it works but I need the gray one. What did I miss?

The code is:

```python
def align_images(image1_path, image2_path):
    img1 = cv.imread(image1_path)  
    img2 = cv.imread(image2_path) 

    imgGray1 = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgGray2 = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    blurred1 = cv.GaussianBlur(imgGray1, (5, 5), 0)
    blurred2 = cv.GaussianBlur(imgGray2, (5, 5), 0)

    threshold = 127

    dark_parts1 = np.zeros_like(blurred1)
    dark_parts1[blurred1 > threshold] = 255

    dark_parts2 = np.zeros_like(blurred2)
    dark_parts2[blurred2 > threshold] = 255

    # cv.imshow("Image 1", dark_parts1)
    # cv.imshow("Image 2", dark_parts2)

    img1 = dark_parts1
    img2 = dark_parts2

    orb = cv.ORB_create()

    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    bf = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    if len(matches) > 10:
        src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:10]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:10]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        M, mask = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)

        img1_transformed = cv.warpPerspective(img1, M, (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]))

        mask = np.zeros_like(img2, dtype=np.uint8)
        roi_corners = np.int32([[[0, 0], [0, img2.shape[0]-1], [img2.shape[1]-1, img2.shape[0]-1], [img2.shape[1]-1, 0]]])
        ignore_mask_color = (255,)
        cv.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)

        border_color = (255, 0, 0)
        border_thickness = 2

        cv.rectangle(mask, (0, 0), (mask.shape[1] - 1, mask.shape[0] - 1), border_color, thickness=border_thickness)

        img2_masked = cv.bitwise_and(img2, mask)
        img_combined = cv.add(img2_masked, img1_transformed)

        img_combined = cv.add(img2_masked, img1_transformed)

        cv.imshow("Aligned Image", img_combined)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print("Error")
align_images('photos/cropped4.png', 'photos/test_map.pgm')
```

Comment: "but it's not working properly every time" is not very clear.  In what way does it go wrong. Please give more details.  Also show some images.  Where did it go wrong?  Do you get any error messages.

Comment: Do you want something like this? The red circles over black rectangle with same sizes..https://ibb.co/B64TYdy